# Как начать писать приложения на Go?

Tags: golang

Как начать писать приложения на Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установить mercurial.

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

Скачать исходный код.

```
hg clone -r release https://go.googlecode.com/hg/ go
```

Собрать выпуск.

```
cd go/src
./all.bash
```

Создать файл привет.go с кодом.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Привет, мир.\n")
}
```

Прописать пути к go/bin.

```
export PATH=$PATH:.../go/bin
```

Собрать и выполнить (например, так).

```
8g пример.go && 8l пример.8 && ./8.out
```