# Как написать makefile для пакета?

Tags: golang

Добрый вечер!

Пришел сюда по поиску, искал инфу по Go. Посмотрел их сайт golang.org - интересно, но не все понятно, особенно english. Решил немного поспрашивать здесь :)

Первый вопрос, как писать makefile для пакета?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Когда используешь gomake, makefile очень простой.

```
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.inc

TARG=hello
GOFILES=hello.go

include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.pkg
```

Также посмотрите похожие вопросы на форуме.

- [Как начать писать приложения на Go?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-go)
- [Как написать модульный тест для приложения на Go?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/407/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-go)

Answer (score 0):

```
# prerequisite: GOROOT and GOARCH must be defined

# defines $(GC) (compiler), $(LD) (linker) and $(O) (architecture)
include $(GOROOT)/src/Make.$(GOARCH)

# name of the package (library) being built
TARG=hello

# source files in package
GOFILES=\
    hello.go

# test files for this package
GOTESTFILES=\
    hello_test.go

# build "main" executable
main: package
    $(GC) -I_obj main.go
    $(LD) -L_obj -o $@ main.$O
    @echo "Done. Executable is: $@"

clean:
    rm -rf *.[$(OS)o] *.a [$(OS)].out _obj _test _testmain.go main

package: _obj/$(TARG).a

# create a Go package file (.a)
_obj/$(TARG).a: _go_.$O
    @mkdir -p _obj/$(dir)
    rm -f _obj/$(TARG).a
    gopack grc $@ _go_.$O

# create Go package for for tests
_test/$(TARG).a: _gotest_.$O
    @mkdir -p _test/$(dir)
    rm -f _test/$(TARG).a
    gopack grc $@ _gotest_.$O

# compile
_go_.$O: $(GOFILES)
    $(GC) -o $@ $(GOFILES)

# compile tests
_gotest_.$O: $(GOFILES) $(GOTESTFILES)
    $(GC) -o $@ $(GOFILES) $(GOTESTFILES)

# targets needed by gotest

importpath:
    @echo $(TARG)

testpackage: _test/$(TARG).a

testpackage-clean:
    rm -f _test/$(TARG).a _gotest_.$O
```

Первый пример который нашел google...